# Get every nth occurrence of every id

Tags: mysql

I have the following table with random data:

```
+--+-----+
|id|data | // + Any other Constant rows
+--+-----+
|1 |P    | // 1. of id1
+--+-----+ 
|1 |Q    | // 2. of id1
+--+-----+
|2 |R    | // 1. of id2
+--+-----+
|3 |S    | // 1. of id3
+--+-----+
|3 |a    | // 2. of id3
+--+-----+
|3 |C    | // 3. of id3
+--+-----+
```

Let's say, i need every SECOND entry of every id.

The result should be:

```
+--+-----+
|id|data | // + Any other Constant rows
+--+-----+
|1 |Q    | // 2. of id1
+--+-----+
|3 |a    | // 2. of id3 and none of id2
+--+-----+
```

I have no clue. I know how to get the first of each id

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, data FROM tablename
```

But that doesn't solve my problem with the nth entry. The table is simplified: An Unique ID is also existing (if it solves anything)

Does someone have an answer?

Comment: You have no way of establishing an order on these rows. Until you do, this problem isn't obviously solvable (without recourse to a hack)

Comment: And 3-a is the second entry for id=3 because...?

Comment: @GilliusMaximus ...because there is also an unique identifier. My fault, i wrote it, but didn't added it to the example table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this and it works.  This may be a bit more efficient as it does not use a join, but reads through the records in the table only once

```
set @row_num:=0;
set @lastid:=0;
Select id, data from
(select id, data, if(id<>@lastid, @row_num:=1, @row_num:=@row_num+1) as row_number, @lastid:=id from tablename order by id) temptab
where row_number = 2
```

Basically, you are building a row number counter into your select statement.  The last_id bit partitions that so the row number restarts with every new id.

Comment: @RagingBull - my mistake, I work with both sqlserver and mysql and do not always keep straight which has which features.  This should now work.

Comment: No problem, mate. I also used to work with SQL Server rather than mysql :)

Comment: @RagingBull sorry for "unchoose" your answer. Even if you solution is awesome (and helps me on an other problem) in this case GiliusMaximus is right.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT `id`,`data`
FROM
(SELECT t1.id, t1.data, count(*) as row_number 
   FROM TableName t1
   JOIN TableName t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.data >= t2.data
   GROUP BY t1.id, t1.data) as temptable
WHERE row_number=2
```

**Explanation:**

`row_number` column is a sequential number of the records partitioned by `id` column.

If you execute the innerquery, it would result something like this:

```
id        row_number
--------------------
1         1
1         2
2         1
3         1
3         2 
3         3
```

And using the outerquery, we are selecting records with `row_number=2`.

**Important:**
You should use the other unique column (as you have mentioned in your comment below your question) instead of `data`. Because, it is partitioned based on the **order** of `data` column.

**EDIT:**

Here the condition `t1.id = t2.id AND t1.data >= t2.data` is used to order by the content based on `t2.data`. Then we create a column `row_number` based on the criteria such as order by `id` and partitioned by `data`.

Comment: Wow, that. is. awesome! If you have the time, could you explain what t1.data >= t2.data does?

Comment: @Mruf: See the edit in my answer for explanation. Also notice that, you should use any column with incrementing values instead of `data` (other than `id` - which is already used here). Because, it is partitioned based on the **order of** `data` column.

Comment: Are you suer that will bi correct for *id=3*, as related to your explanation and t1.data>= t2.data the second will be *data  c* as S > a > c

Comment: @GevorgMargaryan: I know, I just gave it as a sample for `row_number` column. Please see my previous reply to @Mruf in comments. OP says, he has another unique field in his table.

Comment: Using a join to read through the records a second time, just to count them, when they are already being read in your first query, seems inefficient.  Better to just use a counter.

Answer (score 0):

> **Disclaimer:**
>   This is probably not the best answer. I was just looking for another solutions than my usual one and thought it could be interesting to share.

Here's how to solve this issue using subqueries in the `SELECT` clause:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    data,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table_name AS t2
        WHERE
            t1.id = t2.id
            AND t1.data >= t2.data
    ) AS nth
FROM table_name AS t1
HAVING nth = 2
```

It looks pretty much like @RagingBull's answer, and is worse as the subquery is executed for each row.